# How to use SpringBootServletInitializer when using a jar packaging for spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class in my spring boot app which extends the SpringBootServletInitializer, in this class I load the spring datasource details at runtime, this works fine when I package my application as WAR but when I change it to jar SpringBootServletInitializer is ignored. And found from documentation that SpringBootServletInitializer is only called when we run the app as WAR.

Is there an equivalent when running the spring boot application as jar, I want to set the spring datasource details at runtime by pulling the db details from secrets.

This is what I do in the class that extends SpringBootServletInitializer

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException 
....

servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.datasource.driver-class-name", dbClassName);
servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.datasource.url", dbURL);
servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.datasource.username", dbUserName);
servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.datasource.password", dbPWD);
```

Comment: "I want to set the spring datasource details at runtime by pulling the db details from secrets." -  Can you explain or give an example?

Comment: The code snippet where I am setting the spring datasource properties to servlet context, want to do the same when I run as JAR. The existing code only works when I run it as WAR.

Comment: can you tell where you're getting dbClassName and other variables from?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `CommanLineRunner` interface with a callback run() method which can be invoked at application startup after the Spring application context is instantiated like :

```
@Component
public class CommandLineAppStartupRunner implements CommandLineRunner,ServletContextAware {
    private static final Logger LOG =
      LoggerFactory.getLogger(CommandLineAppStartupRunner.class);
 
    private ServletContext context;

    @Override
    public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
        //provide what you want here
        LOG.info("This is triggered");
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
       this.context = servletContext;
    }
}
```